Change correlation plot legend text colour
In the uploaded image under the code, I would like the black text marked with the red line to be white. I'm not sure how to write the code to address this issue.
The code I've used is:
# Paste or type your script code here:
# Load necessary libraries
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
library(corrplot)

# Ensure that the dataset is not empty
if(nrow(dataset) > 0) {
    # Compute the correlation matrix
    cor_matrix <- cor(dataset, use = "complete.obs")
    
    # Increase plot size and adjust margins for better readability
    par(mar = c(4, 4, 2, 2), oma = c(2, 2, 2, 2), mfrow = c(1, 1))
    options(repr.plot.width=10, repr.plot.height=8)
    
    # Define custom color palette
    custom_col <- colorRampPalette(c("#8B0000", "#FFD700", "#006400"))(200)
    
    # Set plot background color and text color
    par(bg = "#003165", col.lab = "white", col.axis = "white", col.main = "white", col.sub = "white")
    
    # Plot the correlation matrix using corrplot with custom settings
    corrplot(cor_matrix, method = "color", type = "upper", 
             tl.col = "white", tl.srt = 45, 
             addCoef.col = "white", number.cex = 0.7,
             col = custom_col)
} else {
    plot.new()
    par(bg = "#003165")
    text(0.5, 0.5, "No data available", cex = 1.5, col = "white")
}

Correlation plot:


I don't think there is an argument for this in corrplot (e.g. cl.col), and while the text colour can be added via the dots in colorlegend this is not possible due to how colorlegend is called within corrplot; there is no way to pass a colour. However, I think using par(col="green") may be okay, as most of all the  other pot colours are controlled by arguments within corrplot.

@user20650 par(col="green") works, please post as answer.
